# Loading CSV data with NaN into AWS Redshift

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load a CSV file from AWS S3 into AWS Redshift.  The CSV file contains a line like:

> 15,NaN,0

The table was created via:

> CREATE TABLE foo (a INT, b DOUBLE PRECISION, c INT);

And I am trying to load the table using the COPY command:

> COPY foo (a, b, c) FROM "s3://" CREDENTIALS ... CSV;

And I get an error complaining:

> Invalid digit value 'N'

Trying to load that same line via an INSERT statement manually works just fine:

> INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c) VALUES (15, 'NaN', 0);

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to tell Redshift to load NaN as a NULL if that is what you want to do.

For example:

```
COPY foo from 's3://xxx' credentials 'xxxx' DELIMETER AS ',' NULL 'NaN';
```

This should execute successfully and insert a NULL into the table instead of NaN.

Comment: I actually wanted to load it as NaN rather than NULL (Redshift support the NaN construct for double precision columns), but it appears that this may not be possible from CSV?